# I want to draw String(which is actually a number) inside a circle?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to add String(1-10) inside a circle?
Here is the code for the circle

```
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 210, 100, 240, 220)
```

Here is the string i want to insert

```
Dim ls_str as String = "5"
```

Is there any way to do this???

Comment: If only there were a [Graphics.DrawString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Graphics.DrawString` and the `Graphics.MeasureString` methods.

Like so

```
Dim StringSize as SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(ls_str, Font) 'Use the font you want
e.Graphics.DrawString(ls_str, Font, CInt(210 + 240 / 2 - StringSize.Width / 2), _  
                                    CInt(100 + 220 / 2 - StringSize.Height / 2))
```

This draws the string in the center of the ellipse that you used. Adjust the coordinates accordingly.

Comment: Always use TextRenderer, Graphics.'DrawString() is only appropriate for high-resolution devices.  Printers.